# Best way to process X number of threads at a time in a loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm starting a remote process for hundreds of servers and want to run about 3 threads at a time. So first I'd like to queue up 3 threads and have them each run the `processData()` function, then the rest of the items within the forloop have to wait until the queue opens up to run that function so I can continue processing 3 threads in parallel at any given time until completion. What is the best way to go about doing this?

```
foreach (ServerData serv in servers) { 
  processData(...)
}
```

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Parallel.ForEach functionality. It also contains some options to customize how many threads will be running at the same time. If you don't specify anything, it will create the threads acccording to the available memory/CPU processing capacity available.

Example:

`Parallel.ForEach(servers, (serv) =>
            {
                //processData function...
            });`

If you want to run only 3 threads at the same time:

`Parallel.ForEach(servers, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, (serv) =>
            {
                //processData function...
            });`

More information about Parallel.ForEach available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Cool. Any idea how this compares to a threadpool (if at all related?)